# Method Declaration kotlin async{}

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-android-extensions

I was wondering what would be the correct declaration for a long running task.

```
suspend fun methodName(image: Bitmap?): String? = async {
   // heavy task
}.await()
```

OR

```
fun methodName(image: Bitmap?): String? {
   //heavyTask
}
```

And in code use

```
async{
   methodName()
}.await()
```

The First one restricts the heavy operation to be performed on the background thread always. So, it's safe (In a way that it will be run on background thread, so that new Devs will be sure to use it in suspendable construct).

Which is the better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `suspend` keyword is a strong warning for the user to prevent a particular function to be used in sensitive threads. But it may not be always the case. as said in [coroutines documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html#suspending-functions) :

> the library can decide to proceed without suspension, if the result for the call in question is already available

If the "heavy task" is meant to be straightforward. (example: copying a file) I personally just add suspend to the function without creating a coroutine. The user is in full charge of where this function will be called.

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
suspend fun copy(input: File, output: File) {
   //copying
}
```

If the "heavy task" is composed of others `suspend` functions. The warning is generally the `couroutineContext` in the function parameter. And internally it use functions like [`withContext()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental/with-context.html).

> *withContext* : suspends until it completes, and returns the result

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
suspend fun copyMultiple(context: CoroutineContext, pairFiles: List<Pair<File, File>>) {
    pairFiles.forEach { (input, output) ->
        withContext(context) { 
            copy(input, output)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use `withContext()` instead of `async{}.await()` in your case.

Regarding your question, IMHO, it's better to use construction like this:

```
suspend fun methodName(image: Bitmap?): String? = withContext(CommonPool) {
   // heavy task
}
```

Comment: The Question is, Whether I should give control ‘to execute Non-UI dependent heavy task on any thread to developer’ or I shouldn’t.

Comment: @Viking93 depends on what are you trying to do. If you are creating public API of a library it's better to delegate threading work to developer because you shouldn't force other developers to use Kotlin, coroutines, etc. 
Otherwise, if this code will be used within your team only, my example is what you need because it uses your stack of technologies and helps to avoid possible threading problems (you can specify coroutine context only once).